# mybatis + spring boot 1.4.2 : MybatisAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB Constructor threw exception NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mybatis

I am getting this error while trying to deploy spring boot 1.4.2 application to tomcat 7 :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'applicationDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationDao' defined in file [E:\sources\apache-tomcat-7.0.86\webapps\OnlineChannelBackend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes\com\pack\dao\ApplicationDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.MybatisAutoConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.MybatisAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f214bdd7]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Object' available: expected single matching bean but found 4: &applicationDao,systemEnvironment,contextParameters,contextAttributes
```

my related build gradle :

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.6 //java6
targetCompatibility = 1.6

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-legacy:1.1.0.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.4.2.RELEASE')
    compile('org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:1.3.2')
    compile('com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.1.0.7.0') //java6
    providedRuntime('org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:7.0.59') // java6
    compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat', name: 'tomcat-jdbc', version: '7.0.59'
```

and In com.pack.dao I have 3 mapper interfaces annotated with `@Mapper` and corresponding xml files in corresponding folder in resources ... the application was running fine with spring boot 2 but once I started changing it to spring boot 1.4.2 I couldn't get it to work

Comment: do you have multiple datasources.

Comment: No ...and  Currently I am just using jdbc connection... No data source

Comment: Ok , Dif you try my answer below

Comment: I am trying it right now

Comment: Ok changed my answer, had the wrong class name before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it was working in previous spring version, i believe you have your configuration files, so you may need to exclude spring auto configurer for my batis.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MybatisAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: thanks a million ... It saved my day ... actually I defined a datasource programmatically and it worked